# C++ variadic template 'contains no parameter packs' when constexpr if should avoid?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, constexpr, fold

I am using some c++ 20 features such as the fold operator to gain the size of a variadic `template` at compile time. I am then using this size in a `constexpr if` to avoid any usage of the `variadic template` if there are no templates provided.

However i am still getting the error:

```
src/engine/inb/component.h:39:68: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
   39 |                 swallowTemplateExpansion(i_addComponent<_Components>(inheritor)...);
      |                                                                    ^
src/engine/inb/component.h:39:80: error: expansion pattern '((((cosmic::ComponentHolder<_Child>*)this)->cosmic::ComponentHolder<_Child>::i_addComponent < <expression error>) > (inheritor))' contains no parameter packs
   39 |                 swallowTemplateExpansion(i_addComponent<_Components>(inheritor)...);
      |                                                                                ^~~
```

Which is telling me that the compiler evaluates the else statement anyway? `constexpr` avoids code like this at compile time so it shouldn't give me this error.

here is the code:

```
template<typename _Child>
    struct ComponentHolder
    {
    private:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component<_Child>>> components{};
        int i_addComponent(_Child* inheritor)
        {
            components.push_back(std::make_shared<Component<_Child>>(inheritor));
            return 0;
        }
    public:
        template<typename... _Components>
        constexpr ComponentHolder(_Child* inheritor)
        {
            constexpr auto _Size = (sizeof(_Components) + ...);
            if constexpr (_Size == 0)
            {
                return;
            } 
            else {
                swallowTemplateExpansion(i_addComponent<_Components>(inheritor)...);
            }
        }
    };
```

And `swallowTemplateExpansion` is just a blank consumer void function:

```
template<typename... T>
    void swallowTemplateExpansion(T&&... x)
    {}
```

Why is my `constexpr if` still trying to unpack the `variadic template` when i have told the compiler if its size is 0, don't unpack the `variadic template`?

thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you using MSVC (Visual studio)?

Comment: With `swallowTemplateExpansion`, order is not guaranteed. With comma operator (`(i_addComponent<_Components>(inheritor), ...);`) left to right order is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by providing the template argument to the `i_addComponent` function, a very silly mistake.

```
template<typename _Component>
        int i_addComponent(_Child* inheritor)
        {
            components.push_back(std::make_shared<_Component>(inheritor));
            return 0;
        }
```